# SQL Server Global Sleep

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In order to force my team to write async code even for small operations (that in their dev environment return instantaneously), I would like to force-set a sleep on every query that the app executes against our sql server...

We use EF6.

How can I make the query generator of EF6 include a "WAITFOR DELAY" before the statements?

Comment: You want to introduce an arbitrary delay on every query?  That seems... counter-productive.  And it doesn't seem like it would "force" the developers to do anything about it, it would just make everything slower.  (Even when using `async` it will make everything slower.)  It seems like an ounce of code review is going to produce better results than a pound of workarounds here.

Comment: @David yes i know.... its a price im willing to pay to have a non-freezing interface... as for code reviews, i have already try that... it didn't work as expected... people just didn't review as carefully as required...

Answer (score 4):

you would need create a [Interceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx), in the "Executing" methods you can modify the query that is being executed and add whatever statements you want to add. You can even check `interceptionContext.IsAsync` to see if the method being called is a async method or not and only add the delay on the non Async calls.

However I agree with [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058541/sql-server-global-sleep#comment50138255_31058541), this will not "make" anyone do anything, having code reviews on check-in will make async adoption much higher than adding arbitrary waits to your program.

Comment: or since you can detect if it's async, make it crash(throw new exception...) if it is not async... at least now they will be forced to use async :-)

Comment: i know that it will not "make" but the argument "i did not knew that calling this method caused a database trip... i though that the info came from XPTO" will no longer apply